# What is the Correct Syntax for navigate to a Child Route using "this._router.navigate(['Results'])"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I found lot of answers which used [routerLink] for navigation to Child Components, but not using **"this._router.navigate(['Result'])"**

here is my Code,**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';     
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet} from    'angular2/router';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search'
import {AttractionComponent} from './attraction/attraction'
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile'

@Component({
  selector: 'interest-app',
  templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet]
})


@RouteConfig([
{ 
  path: '/search/...',
  name: 'SearchHotel',
  component: SearchComponent,
  useAsDefault: true
```

**search.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {ResultsComponent} from '../results/results';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
{ 
    path: '/results/...',
    name: 'Results',
    component: ResultsComponent,
    useAsDefault: true

}  ])
export class SearchComponent {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    console.log('Child component',_router);
  }

  private viewresult() {
    this._router.navigate(['Results']);
  }   
}
```

its work fine when I use **useAsDefault: true**, but when I call the "viewresult()" I got this error

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Link "["Results"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction
```

So I want to know is it possible to route to child components using `this.route.navigate` instead using `[routerLink]`.If does I want to know the correct Syntax.

**results.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {HotelComponent} from '../hotel/hotel';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'views/results.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]})

@RouteConfig([
{ 
    path: '/hotel',
    name: 'Hotel',
    component: HotelComponent        
}    
])

export class ResultsComponent { 

constructor(private _router:Router)
 {

}

 private viewhotel()
{
    this._router.navigate(['Hotel']);
} }
```

Comment: Please add the routes you have on the `ResultsComponent` to your question.

Comment: I added the ResultsComponent, the Thing is, I want to go to the nested route when I click a button which has the method "viewresult()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need either remove `/...` from

  path: '/results/...',

to

```
   path: '/results',
```

- add `useAsDefault:true` to a route in `ResultsComponent`

```
 @RouteConfig([{ 
    path: '/hotel',
    name: 'Hotel',
    component: HotelComponent,
    useAsDefault: true        
 }])
```

- or change your navigate command to

```
this._router.navigate(['Results', 'Hotel']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day, it would be better if u could explain shortly what happened here i would be very thankfull